# VBA- Delaying subroutine until API response

Tags: excel, vba, api

I am trying to find the minimum value of a column and then set that value as the minimum bound of a chart automatically when a cell value changes. The problem is I am using the Alpha Vantage API to get the data and it takes around 2 seconds when the cell changes which causes the code to break. I tried to use the .Wait method and using a loop to delay the .min function, however the API response is also delayed. How do I still continue the API?

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("K1")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
    
    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long
    Dim min As Double
   
   
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (10 * 1000)
    
    Do

        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents

    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
  
    Sheet2.Activate
    
    min = WorksheetFunction.min(Range("F2", Range("F1").End(xlDown)))
    Range("M1").Value2 = min
        

 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the API call? Can you add the min calculation to the end of that code if through vba?

Comment: The API is a excel add-on version, and I am calling through a function within a cell.